# Understandings of split() variable assignation in if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

so far my code working perfectly as long as my first element is single-letter input but somehow value is not assigning to a variable when I input multiple letters to the first element

**I just want to understand why the code is not assigning value when the first element is double or multiple letters?**

Code:

```
date=input("Enter the date: ")
if date.find('-')==True:
    dd,mm,yy=date.split('-')
elif date.find('/')==True:
    dd,mm,yy=date.split('/')
else:
    print('Incorrect Input',date)
print(dd,mm,yy)
```

Output Case 1:

```
Enter the date: 0-0-0
0 0 0
```

Output Case 2:

```
Enter the date: s/ss/ssss
s ss ssss
```

Output Case 3:

```
Enter the date: 10-10-10
Incorrect Input 10-10-10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\**\**\**\**\**", line 8, in <module>
    print(dd,mm,yy)
NameError: name 'dd' is not defined
```

Output Case 4:

```
Enter the date: ss/sss/ss
Incorrect Input ss/sss/ss
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\**\**\**\**\**", line 8, in <module>
    print(dd,mm,yy)
NameError: name 'dd' is not defined
```

Comment: The find function returns the index of the argument. `True` is practically equal to `1` in python and when the day is single digit, find returns 1 and the if block will run. But when it's 2 characters, find returns 2, so both the if blocks will not be executed. Check if the return value of find is not `-1` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20find#str.find) returns the index where the substring is found in the string, or -1 if not. It does not return `True` or `False`.

When you have a single digit before the first delimiter (`-` or `/`) `str.find()` returns 1. In Python, 1 also happens to be equal to `True`.

```
>>> True
True
>>> int(True)
1
>>> True == 1
True
```

That's why it works if there is a single character before the `-` or `/`.

In any other case `find()` returns -1 if the substring is not found. or a larger number, e.g. 2 neither of which is equal to `True`.

```
>>> 2 == True
False
>>> -1 == True
False
```

Fix your code by testing whether `find()` returns -1:

```
if date.find('-') == -1:
    dd, mm, yy = date.split('-')
```

Answer (score 1):

`find()` doesn't return `True` or `False`, [it's an offset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

> Return the lowest index in the string where substring *sub* is found within the slice `s[start:end]`. Optional arguments *start* and *end* are interpreted as in slice notation. Return `-1` if *sub* is not found.

So, your code becomes:

```
date=input("Enter the date: ")
if date.find('-') != -1:
    dd,mm,yy=date.split('-')
elif date.find('/') != -1:
    dd,mm,yy=date.split('/')
else:
    print('Incorrect Input',date)
print(dd,mm,yy)
```